# Netty and Project Loom

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, netty, project-loom

I may be wrong, but as far as I understand, the whole **Reactive/Event Loop** thing, and **Netty** in particular, was invented as an answer to the **C10K+** problem. It has obvious drawbacks, as all your code now becomes **Async**, with *ugly callbacks*, *meaningless stack traces*, and therefore hard to maintain and to reason about.

**Go**'s language with goroutines was a solution, now they can write **Sync** code and also handle **C10K+**. So now **Java** comes up with [**Loom**](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/loom/), which essentially copies the **Go**'s solution, soon we will have **Fibers** and **Continuations** and will be able to write **Sync** code again.

So the questions are:

1. When the **Loom** is released in production, doesn't it make **Netty** kinda obsolete?
2. If we have **Fibers** and **Continuations** in **Java**, can we write nice **Sync** code and be ok with **C10K+** without **Netty**?
3. Are there any advantages, for performance or solving **C10K+**, in writing **Async** code and using **Netty**, after production release of **Loom**?

I understand that **Netty** is more than just **Reactive/Event Loop** framework, it also has all the codecs for various protocols, which implementations will be useful somehow anyway, even afterwards.

Comment: same question here https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/d9nxpo/r2dbc_08_release_candidate_1_released/

Comment: @bodrin Also, https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8439

Comment: As far as I know, continuations won't be available in Loom, they are internal

Comment: @fps Internal in JVM? Eventually, when Loom is merged into JVM, they may be called internal, yes ‍♂️

Comment: @bxq I mean that they won't be exposed via a public API

Answer (score 2):

I'm focusing on the reactive parts of Netty because those you seem to mostly want to address answering on a general level:

Currently reactive programming paradigms are often used to solve performance problems, not because they fit the problem. Those should be covered completely via project Loom.

However, some problems may remain where the reactive programming approach makes sense and is more straight forward to read than imperative code. 
Reactive frameworks are typically stream oriented and are well suited to combine elements and operations on different entity/data streams. They also provide straight forward local event bus solutions with their provider/subscriber model. In such cases the reactive model might still be the best choice, performant and more readable than an imperative approach. But indeed, project loom should make all the "misuse" due to lack of better support in the native language structures obsolete.